# OleDbDataReader.GetString Exception - Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, ms-access-2007, oledbdatareader

When my C# (.NET 3.5) application attempts to access a MS Access 2007 database the `OleDbReader.GetString()` method is throwing an exception:

> Specified cast is not valid.

What am I doing wrong?

```
OleDbCommand cmd = null;
OleDbDataReader reader = null;
String queryString = "SELECT ids.ENUM_H, bas.[BAS BACnet Object Type/Instance] FROM [OV2 BAS] AS bas INNER JOIN [OV2 RefID] AS ids ON bas.[Ref ID] = ids.[Ref ID]";

this.Open();

try
{
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(queryString, this._conn);
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (!reader.HasRows)
    {
        Exception e = new Exception("Read of mapping table returned no results.");
        throw e;
    }
    else
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Int32 index;
            String classTypeString = null; // = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal(MappingTable.OBJECT_IDENTIFIER_COLUMN_NAME)).Substring(0, 2);
            int it = reader.GetOrdinal(MappingTable.OBJECT_IDENTIFIER_COLUMN_NAME);
            string st = reader.GetString( it );  // <-- **Exception is thrown here** <--
            st = st.Substring(0,2);
            String classIdString = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal(MappingTable.OBJECT_IDENTIFIER_COLUMN_NAME)).Substring(2);

            index = Convert.ToInt32(classIdString);
            ClassIds[index, 0] = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ENUM_H"));
            ClassIds[index, 1] = classTypeString;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    throw e;
}

this.Close();
```

I know that the `Open()` and `Close()` methods work.  Something is wrong with my query, or the way I am processing the results.  Thanks.

Comment: If you try `string st = reader.GetString(0)` does it work?

Comment: What's the type of that column? If you call `reader.GetValue()` instead, what happens? Might that value be null?

Comment: Yes, it does, but it returns values for `ids.ENUM_H`, which is expected.  When I step through `it` does evaluate to 1 as expected.  When I change it to `string st = reader.GetString(1)` I get the same error.  It's like it's not pulling anything from the database for `bas.[BAS BACnet Object Type/Instance]`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Both columns are of type Text.

Comment: @JimFell: And what does `reader.IsDBNull(1)` return?

Comment: @JonSkeet: It returns true.  What does that mean?

Comment: @JimFell: It means there's no data for that field in that row. Will add an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, so `reader.IsDBNull(1)` is returning true... which means there's no data in that particular row for that field.

You need to work out what that means, and handle it appropriately. You may want to modify the query to not include such rows, or use `reader.IsDBNull` to *detect* such rows and act appropriately, e.g. using a default value for the field.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Now that I know what's happening I can handle it.  I looked in the database and you were right; there is no data in that row for that field.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens because of Cell format. If your Cell format is set to **General** you should change it to **Text** .